# Get host entry async freezes

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a problem that occurs when i have deployed the code to the production server. It does not happen locally on my computer. When i run the line

```
var host = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(adresse);
```

The production environment freezes or awaits indefinitely. Why does this happen?

Here is the code:

```
    public async Task<string> HentAsync(string ip)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ip) || kLoopbackIp.Contains(ip))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        if (IpHostname.ContainsKey(ip))
        {
            UpdateAndRemoveOldElements(ip);

            return IpHostname[ip].Item1;
        }

        try
        {
            IPAddress adresse = IPAddress.None;
            if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ip, out adresse))
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            var host = await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync(adresse);
            string hostname = host.HostName;

            IpHostname.AddOrUpdate(ip,
                                   new Tuple<string, DateTime>(hostname, DateTime.Now),
                                   (x, y) => new Tuple<string, DateTime>(hostname, DateTime.Now));
            return hostname;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Tar i mot exception og returnerer tom string
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:
The async method is called like this from a sync method that is doing the same thing (could this be the culprit).

```
public string Hent(string ip)
{
    return HentAsync(ip).Result;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you call the synchronous version of it?

Comment: + what is the difference between production environment and your environment ? OS ?  installed .net version ?

Comment: The .net version is the same as my local environment. Only difference is that i am running IIS express and the production is runnin IIS

Comment: Are you using `HentAsync(ip).Result` or some variation of it? If your synchronization context is blocked it could result in a deadlock.

Comment: Is your DNS server address set up correctly on the server machine? Can you resolve hostnames via commandline?

Comment: Yes @Dirk, i have updated the question with the code that is calling it.

Comment: @RGraham - The sync  version of the same call (Dns.GetHostEntry()) works fine.

Comment: This is known "problem", I recently answered a question about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572908/using-async-and-await-to-break-up-database-call-with-dapper/24573088#24573088).

Comment: Is it possible to keep the code "DRY" with this deadlock problem?

Comment: @StianStandahl You could try adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to your awaitables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the origin of this call is running on the UI thread; perhaps the call to `Hent()` updates a UI element?

The problem is well documented here: [await works but calling task.Result hangs/deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248680/await-works-but-calling-task-result-hangs-deadlocks)

`Hent()` calls `HentAsync()` and then `await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync()`. This last call spawns a new thread, but wants to return to the calling thread when it has finished, which in this case is the UI thread, but it cannot do this because `.Result` is squatting on the thread rather than yielding it temporarily like it would have with `await`.

As @spender and @Dirk point out, one solution is to add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to `await Dns.GetHostEntryAsync()`. In fact you should add this to every `await` where you don't care what thread context the function continues in.

This approach is still quite fragile though, as any time you forget to do it or execution takes a path with an unmodified `await`, the problem will happen again. The best option is to make the top-level UI-threaded function `async` and then `await` every function call that could cause a delay. This is the canonical use-case for async / await and leads to flat, easy to follow code with very little chance of deadlock.